# How can I find the Weights of a Subalgebra

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm currently trying to understand how we can derive the weights of a subalgebra of a given representation of a Lie group.

For example, if we start with the 16-dimensional representation of $SO(10)$, which corresponds to highest weight $(1,0,0,0,0,0)$, we have a long list with weights that define this representation. If we then consider, for example, the subalgebra $SU(5) \otimes U(1)$. How can I find the weights and therefore the representations for this subalgebra?

Comment: What is a "subalgebra" of a given representation ? $E_6,SO(10),U(1)$ are Lie groups. Do you mean "subrepresentation" ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes probably this is the correct term. I was thinking about the algebras that correspond to these groups and their representations, which are given by the corresponding weights

Comment: @DietrichBurde In other words: Given a representation of a group (which means a list of weights), how can I compute the corresponding subgroup representations (which means a new list of weights)